# Column space of matrix A

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have this matrix here:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
2 & 0 & -1 \\
4 & 0 & -2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

and I reduced it to:

$$B = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1/2 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 
\end{bmatrix}
$$

So I say the columnspace is:
$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
4 \\
0\end{bmatrix}
$$

But the book says

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
2\\
0
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I can see this is a multiple of my answer, but I thought when you find the columnspace you had to use the original columns of $A$ that correspond to the pivot columns of $B$. This was because row operations change the columnspace. I think I'm not fully understanding something here if someone could explain.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the same. This is because the column space is the span of the vectors corresponding to the pivot columns. So
$$\operatorname{span}\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\0\end{bmatrix}=\operatorname{span}\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Recall, for a vector $v$ in a vector space $V$ over a scalar field $\Bbb K$, we have $\operatorname{span}(v)=\{cv:c\in\Bbb K\}$. That is, the span of $v$ is all scalar multiples of $v$.

Comment: Oh yeah, so also, you could choose any of those scalar multiples as the basis of this space then too? @Dave

Comment: Yes. It's a one dimensional space, so the spanning vector is the only basis vector.

Comment: Cheers @ Dave. Thanks a lot.